# how to code according to json data from api in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am a beginner, I am learning d3.js but I am unable to figure out on how to draw a graph or code according to the data is in json format from api.
Here is one of the things I have tried but I am unable to change it according to the new data in another api. Can anybody help me?
where do I make the changes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
  </head>

    <style>

      body {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5em;
        background-color: #74b9ff;
      }

      h1 {
        color: snow;
      }


    </style>


    <body>
    <h1>Bitcoin Prices in U.S. Dollars</h1>
    <script>


  var url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=200&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG";


  d3.json(url).get(function(error, d) {

    var data = d.Data;
    data.forEach(function(d){ d.time = new Date(d.time * 1000) });

    if (error) throw error;

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, width])

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .style("font-size",".8em");

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("font-size",".8em")
      .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", "1.2em")
        .text("Price ($)")


    g.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#ffeaa7")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("d", line);

  });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the correct output for the above mentioned code but I want to change the api to **https://blockchain.info/ticker**

where could I make the changes to make it work?

Comment: They are two different datasets. One has multiple values over time so you can draw a nice line graph. The other are attributes for different kinds of currencies. For this you need a bar chart. What do you want to display with the `blockchain` dataset?

Comment: @rioV8 Sir, I want my graph to change everytime when the json data from api changes. When i refresh though

Comment: @rioV8 i want to see changes in the bitcoin price through graph over time. The graph should change if json data from api changes, when i refresh.

Comment: Yes but a line graph is not the correct one for your blockchain json data the x-value is ordinal not linear. This is a better graph https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah, I have seen it. but its .tsv not the one I am working on. but where do i make the changes to make my graph work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is the convertion rate of bitcoin compared to other coins it does not make sense to plot them all in one graph. The `JPY` would crush all the other bars.

Why buy/sell bitcoin using different coins if they just are conversions given the current rate.

If you draw a single coin values you get the following graph

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("https://blockchain.info/ticker", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data = data.EUR;

  var keys = ["15m", "last", "buy", "sell"];
  x.domain(keys);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(keys, function(k) { return data[k]; })]);

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("price");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(keys)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(k) { return x(k); })
      .attr("y", function(k) { return y(data[k]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(k) { return height - y(data[k]); });
});

</script>
```

Also not useful. Because all the variation is in the top few pixels.

What you need is a way to record the values from the JSON file over time for a particular coin and graph that like your original dataset.

Can be done by fetching the data every x minutes and then modify the graph with the enter/exit/remove `data()` call or just redraw the graph like this.

Place comments before the **DEBUG** sections for the real data. And uncomment the following line

```
//setInterval(getData, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Here I generate dummy data every 5 seconds for the demo.

To prevent out of memory `data` length is limited to 1000 samples.

**Edit**

It now shows the date of the sample on the x-axis.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.p15m { stroke: steelblue;}
.pbuy { stroke: red;}
.plast { stroke: green;}
.psell { stroke: orange;}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = [];

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });

function getData() {
   //DEBUG
   data.push( {"15m": Math.random()*100 + 100, "last": Math.random()*100 + 100, "buy": Math.random()*100 + 100, "sell": Math.random()*100 + 100, "date": new Date() } );
   updateGraph();
   return;
   // DEBUG END

  d3.json("https://blockchain.info/ticker", function(error, dataNew) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var d = dataNew.EUR;
    d.date = new Date();
    data.push();
    if (data.length > 1000) data = data.shift();
    updateGraph();
  });
}

getData();
setTimeout(getData, 5000);

//DEBUG
setInterval(getData, 5 * 1000);
//DEBUG END
//setInterval(getData, 5 * 60 * 1000);

function updateGraph() {
  if (data.length < 2) return;
  svg.select("g").remove(); // clean the graph
  var keys = ["15m", "last", "buy", "sell"];
  var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date));
  var flat = [];
  data.map( d => keys.map(k => d[k]) ).forEach(e => { flat = flat.concat(e); });
  y.domain(d3.extent(flat , function(d) { return d; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price (EUR)");

  g.selectAll("g.key")
   .data(keys)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", d => "key p" + d )
   .append("path")
      .datum(k => data.map( (d, i) => [d.date, d[k]]))
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i comment the debug section. @rioV8

Comment: and you have to uncomment the `//setInterval()` call