# DC.js, crossfilter - generic grouping with varying number of columns

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, composite

I'm trying to create a generic composite chart that would take any csv file, read the columns and create a composite line chart with one line per column.

In this use case, the first column is always TimeStamp in all csv's and this will not be changed, while the rest of the columns may vary.

To get the column names from any csv, I am using the following line of code.

```
var mappedArray = d3.entries(data[0]);
```

Say, my mappedArray is like this :

```
["Date", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

I have created the Dimension for timestamp as follows:

```
var DateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return timeFmt(d[mappedArray[0].key]); });
```

For a single valued group, i would use something like this:

```
var testGrp = DateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){return +d[mappedArray[1].key]; });
```

For a multi valued group, I tried something like this:

```
    var testGrp1 = testDim.group().reduce(
                    function(p,v){
                        ++p.count;
                        p.col1 = +v[mappedArray[1].key];
                        p.col2 = +v[mappedArray[2].key];
                        ...
                        p.coln = +v[mappedArray[n].key];
                        return p;
                    },...
```

But, I cannot hard code like this, as the 'n' in mappedArray[n] may keep changing.

How can I recreate this group by using mappedArray.length?

Comment: have a look at the last snippet in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583965/9938317

Comment: @rioV8, Could you explain this in a dc.js scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You recreate by using the index field operator `[]`. Use a for loop to create as many `p.colX` fields as needed.

```
var testGrp1 = testDim.group().reduce(
    function(p,v){
        ++p.count;
        for (let i = 1; i < mappedArray.length; i++) {
            p["col" + i] = +v[mappedArray[i].key];
        }
        return p;
    },...
```

**Edit**

The answer to your question in the comment about the `chart.compose`.

A possible way of doing is to create a function that constructs the array needed.

```
function makeComposeArray() {
    var composeArr = [];
    for(let i=1; i<=mappedArray.length; i++) {
        composeArr.push(
            dc.lineChart(chart)
              .group(testGrp1, function(d){return d['col'+i]})
              .valueAccessor(function(d){return d.value["col" + i]})
         );
    }
    return composeArr;
}
chart.compose(makeComposeArray());
```

Comment: It worked! If I use similar logic inside chart.compose([
            for(let i=1; i<=mappedArray.length; i++){
             dc.lineChart(chart) .group(testGrp1, function(d){return d['col'+i]}) .valueAccessor(function(d){return d.value["col" + i]}), it gives error (unexpected token for)? How can i fix the code to make it work?

Comment: If I read your example correct and looking at the only example I could find of `chart.compose` I modified the answer.

Comment: The line .group(testGrp1, function(d){return d['col'+i]}) doesn't seem to work as expected. I am using d['col' + i] for legend. I may need to use separate legendText function in this scenario.

Comment: When I use the same logic for chart.title(), the tool tip shows the entire code as a string, insted of the actual output of code. Here is a fiddle I created to show this https://jsfiddle.net/718sqr0a/31/. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass `d` as argument to `toolTipNames` and update line `tooltipArr.push( valueKey[i] + ': ' + d.value["col" + i] );`

Comment: why `var mappedArray = d3.entries(data[0]);` if `var mappedArray = data.columns;` is what you actually need, no need to use the `.key` field

Comment: And `var valueKey = data.columns;`

Comment: Noted. I don't know what i was thinking. Anyways, passing d as an argument worked! Thanks for the help @rioV8